# Get full iso format date and time with colon and “T” separator

Tags: datetime2, isodate

When I use `iso` style with `datetime2` package, I exepect to get the full date format with T separator between date and time and colon “:” between hours, minutes, and seconds.

I expect someting like `2016-11-09T08:32:44`, however, with the following code I just get `2016-11-09122400`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[francais]{babel} 
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage[french]{datetime2} 


\begin{document}
  \DTMsetdatestyle{iso}
  \DTMdisplaydate{2016}{11}{09}{-1}{12}{24}{00}{}{}

\end{document}
```

So, how can I get with `datetime2` the full format like `2016-11-09T08:32:44`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\DTMdisplaydate` accepts only four arguments:

1. Year
2. Month
3. Day
4. Day of week

You're interested in setting not just a *date* style, but an *entire* style that doesn't show the zone:

> 2016-11-09T12:24:00

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french,showzone=false]{datetime2} 

\begin{document}

\DTMsetstyle{iso}
\DTMdisplay{2016}{11}{09}{-1}{12}{24}{00}{}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a little problem. I get `2016-11-09T12 :24`, because of he french `babel` option witch put space before all colon `:` (it’s a french typographic obligation).

Comment: @fauve: Can you provide a minimal example that replicates this behaviour? Just adding `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` to my code doesn't show this.